# Python finding the nearest point between two one dimensional arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two one dimensional arrays with different lengths

`t_1 and t_2 where len(t_1)<len(t_2)`.

I want to find the nearest point in `t_2 for each element in t_1`

my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
t_1 = data[1][0]
t_2 = data[2][0]
sizeT2 = len(t_2)
for i in range (0,len(t_1)):
    x = t_1[i]
    dist = np.sqrt(((t_2 - x[:, :sizeT2])**2).sum(axis=0))
    idx[i] = np.argsort(dist)
```

however this one doesnt work it gives me error: `invalid index to scalar variable`. on line where i compute dist:
sample values for t_1 and t_2:

```
t_1 = [787093248920, 788197478458, 789119542957, 790116608918, 791221791725, 792276904840, 793284327147, 794281387454, 795471722491]

t_2 = [786185938536, 786198456613, 786201269998, 786209682882, 786217046729, 786226031805, 786243417036, 786261786036, 786268379959, 786285296767, 786291818036, 786301118305, 786316936921, 786327079575, 786330177152, 786339472844, 786345463959, 786348981075, 786352899190]
```

Comment: On what line? 2, 6 or 8?

Comment: If `t_1` is 1D, then with `x = t_1[i]`, x would be a scalar and hence `x[:, :sizeT2]` would get an error. So, I am not sure what your code is doing. At least get us a sample representative data and tell us the expected result.

Comment: Can you share the value for `data`

Comment: the expected result is the index of the closest point in t_2 for every point in t_1
   `t_1 = [787093248920, 788197478458, 789119542957, 790116608918, 791221791725, 792276904840, 793284327147, 794281387454,  795471722491]`



    `t_2 = [786185938536, 786198456613, 786201269998, 786209682882, 786217046729, 786226031805, 786243417036, 786261786036, 786268379959, 786285296767, 786291818036, 786301118305, 786316936921, 786327079575, 786330177152, 786339472844, 786345463959, 786348981075, 786352899190]`

Comment: Why are you doing `np.sqrt(( . . . )**2)` ?  Is that supposed to be an abolute value or a Euclidean distance?  Euclidean distance is only meaningful in more than one dimension, and otherwise use `np.abs`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `t_1` and `t_2` are `ndarray`:

```
t_2[np.argmin(np.abs(t_1[:, None] - t_2), axis = 1)]
```

Your toy problem is pretty trivial though, as all elements of `t_1` are greater than all elements of `t_2`

```
array([786352899190, 786352899190, 786352899190, 786352899190,
       786352899190, 786352899190, 786352899190, 786352899190, 786352899190], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I figured afterward the elements in the example are not the best representants. but conider that t_1 has a sampling frequency of 1s and t_2 of 0.01s. so for each t_1 we have 100 t_2. And t_1 and t_2 are pandas.

Comment: Please go back and put the expected output in the question.